# How can I use tkinter library with Python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, import, tk-toolkit

When it comes to import the library. 
I got an error that the module is not found

I'm using Python 2.7 
Windows with 32 bit

Is there a solution?

Comment: Have you installed tkinter?

Comment: Have you more than one Python version installed?

Comment: It's a library, is not it?

Comment: Just one 2.7 How can I install a library?

Comment: Ignore these comments. Tkinter comes with Python. You're just using the wrong name. See my answer.

Comment: @MohamedA.Mahfouz To be precise you would need to install it if you run on Linux/Mac you are on Windows it is installed already, so it does not apply.  See abarnert's answer

Comment: @abarnert yes, you were right.

Comment: @Simon Some linux distros do separate it out into a separate package, but it's preinstalled on Mac, and if you use any installer/package from python.org, and if you build Python yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module was called [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), with a capital `T`, in Python 2.7.

Python 3 renamed most stdlib modules that didn't fit the coding standard (mostly because they'd been added before there was a coding standard). By 2018, most books, YouTube tutorials, Stack Overflow answers, blog posts, etc. are going to show you Python 3, so if you want to or have to keep using Python 2.7 for some reason, you need to know how to find the Python 2 docs.

Fortunately, once you're at the Python 3 docs, this is easy: just go to the little option menu in the navigation bar that says "3.7" or whatever, and change it to "2.7".

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much. It works 